# Why Jetpack Compose compiler mark the composable function has parameter with ImmutableList type unstable in this case

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

To make composable function stable, I used `kotlinx.collections.immutable.ImmutableList` instead of `List`, like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun YourComposition(state: ImmutableList<String>) {
    Log.d(TAG, "YourComposition: $state")
    Text(text = state.toString())
}
```

config gradle script follow the [document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability/diagnose#setup), I got this output:

```
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun YourComposition(
  stable state: ImmutableList<String>
)
```

Yes, it's stable. but if I define a composable function like this:

```kotlin
data class YourDataClass(
    val data: ImmutableList<String>
)

@Composable
fun YourComposition(state: ImmutableList<YourDataClass>) {
    Log.d(TAG, "YourComposition: $state")
    Text(text = state.toString())
}
```

below is its output:

```
restartable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun YourComposition(
  unstable state: ImmutableList<YourDataClass>
)
```

Ok, if I change the type of `YourDataClass#data` to `String`(other stable type with the same effect),
the output will become to this:

```
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun YourComposition(
  stable state: ImmutableList<YourDataClass>
)
```

You will find that `YourClassData#data` cause composable function unstable. But why?